# (standard_in) 1: parse error bash to calculate mean of a record

Tags: bash, function, parsing, while-loop

I keep getting standard in: parser error

```
#!bin/bash


file="0.txt"

if [ -f $file ] ; then
    rm $file
fi


for i in {1..4};
 do cat $i'_Node_770_01_Band_600_Min_Res.txt' >> 0.txt;
done

############# MAXIMUM ############
function maximum() {
   column="$1"
    awk '{print $'$column';}' 0.txt | sort -nr | head -n 1
    return 0
}

############MINIMUM#############
function minimum() {
    column="$1"
    awk '{print $'$column';}' 0.txt | sort -nr | tail -n 1
}   

############AVERAGE###########
function average(){
    max="$1"
    min="$2"
    div="2"
    diff=$(echo "scale=4; $max-$min" | bc)
    ave=$(echo "scale=4; $diff/$div" | bc)
    echo $ave
}

input="0"
while true; do
    read -p "Enter column [1-10] ('q' to quit): " input;

    if [ "$input" == "q" ];
        then
            clear
            echo "Goodbye!"
        break
    elif [ "$input" == "Q" ]; 
       then
            clear
            echo "Goodbye!"
        break
    elif (("$input" < "1")) || (("$input" > "10"));
        then
            clear
            echo -e "\t\t Try again"

    else
        #store maximum in variable max
        maximum $input read -r max
        #store minimum in variable min
        minimum $input read -r min
        #echo $min
        average $max $min 
    break
    fi

done
```

I believe the parser issue is in the function average.  I do not know how to resolve this.  I've tried fixing doing:
max=$(maximum $input)
min=$(minimum $input)
average $max $min
to no avail.

Comment: #!bin/bash => #!/bin/bash

Comment: max=$(maximum $input) is right. 'read', '-r', 'max' is just arguments for function. Add exception handling for null value for max and min.

Comment: As a shorthand for your `if [ -f $file ]` block, you could simply use `:>"0.txt"` to *truncate* (empty) the file if it exists or create an empty file if it does not. Typically you want to *double-quote* any variables used with `test` (e.g. `[...]`) to prevent error in the event the variable contains whitespace or is empty. (here you explicitly set `file` above the test, so there isn't any possibility, but it is good practice). If you want to avoid quoting, use `[[...]]`.

Comment: @thatseeyou, you can enclose your code in comments in *backticks* (e.g. `'\`'`) to set the code portion to fixed-width font and set an off-white background. (just for future reference). It works the same in your answers.

Comment: I reverted back to the previous line of codes I had: `function average(){
    div="2"
    diff=$(echo "scale=4; $1-$2" | bc)
    ave=$(echo "scale=4; $diff/$div" | bc)
    echo $ave
}` and just to show that the values that I am parsing is numeric, here's the message that I am getting: Enter column [1-10] ('q' to quit): 4
-83.3873
-88.7882
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error

Comment: Thank you for your help, guys.  I figured out the problem.  The record was using a delimiter, which I confused for negative values.  By the way, the suggestion to use    `max="${1-0}"
    min="${2-0}"` worked! and since the delimiters were removed first, it is not necessary to do so.  `function average(){
    div="2"
    sum=$(echo "scale=4; $1+$2" | bc)
    ave=$(echo "scale=4; $sum/$div" | bc)
    echo $ave
}` works just fine.  Thank you for your help, once again.

Answer (score 0):

The **parse error** is from the `bc` command and likely a result of an *unset*, *empty*, on *non-numeric* variable used in the calculation; In this case, the culprits are most likely `max` and `min`.

**Example:** If both `max` and `min` are unset, then providing a default (numeric) value will prevent the parse errors from being emitted by `bc`:

```
function average(){
  max="${1:-0}"
  min="${2:-0}"
  ...
}
```

> Ideally, you would incorporate a robust form of validation to the input, which is beyond the scope of the question, but this should help to understand the rationale for the **parse error**.

Comment: thanks for the input. I tried the revision, but it is giving me this:(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: parse error
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: :
(standard_in) 1: parse error; I originally do not have the max="$1" and min="$1" but it is the same error message.

Comment: @CNSp – You are using `max="${1:-0}"` and not `max="${1-:0}"` right (i.e. `colon` before `dash`). You can also remove the colon completely in this case. (e.g. `max="${1-0}"`). The extra `:` makes a difference only when the parameter has been declared, but is empty. [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

Comment: @CNSp – What are the values of `max` and `min` when the `average` function is invoked?

Comment: they all numeric, since it is handing 10 columns of all numeric records. Here's a scenario if a particular column is selected: _Enter column [1-10] ('q' to quit): 4
-83.3873
-88.7882
(standard_in) 2: parse error
(standard_in) 1: parse error_

Comment: so, those two values are from the functions maximum and minimum.  I originally had the codes like this: `function average(){ div="2" diff=$(echo "scale=4; $1-$2" | bc) ave=$(echo "scale=4; $diff/$div" | bc) echo $ave }` the call out function in the main body is
        `maximum $input read -r max
        minimum $input read -r min
        average $max $min` because I thought the values would be stored in variables max and min and those two values would parse to the average function in the $1 and $2

Comment: using `max="${$1:-0}"
    min="${$2:-0}"` gives:   -83.3873 
_-88.7882
hw2test.sh: line 32: ${$1-0}: bad substitution_

Comment: @CNSp - what's with the extra dollar ($)? That's not what I wrote in my comment above.